# Django model field set default user in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I have an existing model in which I want to add a User foreign key ex:

`user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)`

If I set the parameter `default=User.admin` I get an attribute error.

If I try to set `default=User.objects.get(username='admin')` I get the error `ValueError: Cannot serialize: <User: admin>`

How can I set the default to be the `User` named `admin` or any other user?

Comment: What is User admin? What do you expect `User.admin` to be? Are you expecting the current logged-in user?

Comment: @allcaps The admin user that's created alongside django.admin, I'm just looking for how to set it to any user

Comment: Try this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: FYI: There is no admin user created alongside django.admin. There is the admin site and the createsuperuser command. Two separate things.

Comment: @allcaps Yes most people name the superuser admin while testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting primary key?  The user table uses integers for the primary key.